# How to make vertical list navigation on andoid?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation, categories, android-appbarlayout

Can you please tell me how to implement this behavior? Under AppBar has a horizontal menu that allows you to go to the desired category, list location, and it is also automatically selected when scrolling the screenCan you please tell me how to implement this behavior? Under AppBar has a horizontal menu that allows you to go to the desired category, list location, and it is also automatically selected when scrolling the screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wQHe.png)

I looked at the material elements and did not find the necessary data. It’s also unclear how this navigation works in general.

Comment: I found a solution:
https://proandroiddev.com/synchronize-recyclerview-with-tablayout-3c5da4f3b18b
https://github.com/Ahmad-Hamwi/TabSync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish this by utilizing TabLayout and ViewPager/ViewPager2; please consult the official documentation for full guidance.

1. Add dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.0"
}
```

2. Layout for your activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

3. Adapter

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter

class PagerAdapter(activity: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 3

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> Fragment1()
            1 -> Fragment2()
            2 -> Fragment3()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid position")
        }
    }
}
```

4. Setup your Acitivity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val viewPager: ViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
        val tabLayout: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
        val adapter = PagerAdapter(this)

        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        // Connect TabLayout and ViewPager2
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
            when (position) {
                0 -> tab.text = "Tab 1"
                1 -> tab.text = "Tab 2"
                2 -> tab.text = "Tab 3"
            }
        }.attach()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I was looking for, but thanks to your tip on TabLayout, I found a solution on TabSync

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution, and I apologize for the inaccurate answer. Cheers!